# JavaScript - Attach context to async function call?

Tags: javascript, async-await, method-call, asynchronous-method-call

##### Synchronous function call context

In JavaScript, it's easy to associate some context with a synchronous function call by using a stack in a global scope.

```js
// Context management

let contextStack = [];
let context;

const withContext = (ctx, func) => {
  contextStack.push(ctx);
  context = ctx;

  try {
    return func();
  } finally {
    context = contextStack.pop();
  }
};

// Example

const foo = (message) => {
  console.log(message);
  console.log(context);
};

const bar = () => {
  withContext("calling from bar", () => foo("hello"));
};

bar();
```

This allows us to write context-specific code without having to pass around a context object everywhere and have every function we use depend on this context object.

This is possible in JavaScript because of the guarantee of sequential code execution, that is, these synchronous functions are run to completion before any other code can modify the global state.

##### Generator function call context

We can achieve something similar with generator functions. Generator functions give us an opportunity to take control just before conceptual execution of the generator function resumes. This means that even if execution is suspended for a few seconds (that is, the function is not run to completion before any other code runs), we can still ensure that there is an accurate context attached to its execution.

```
const iterWithContext = function* (ctx, generator) {
  // not a perfect implementation

  let iter = generator();
  let reply;

  while (true) {
    const { done, value } = withContext(ctx, () => iter.next(reply));
    
    if (done) {
      return;
    }
    
    reply = yield value;
  }
};
```

##### Question: Async function call context?

It would also be very useful to attach some context to the execution of an async function.

```
const timeout = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const foo = async () => {
  await timeout(1000);
  console.log(context);
};

const bar = async () => {
  await asyncWithContext("calling from bar", foo);
};
```

The problem is, to the best of my knowledge, there is no way of intercepting the moment before an async function resumes execution, or the moment after the async function suspends execution, in order to provide this context.

Is there any way of achieving this?

My best option right now is to not use async functions, but to use [generator functions that behave like async functions](https://medium.com/@davidcallanan/implementing-async-await-syntax-in-vanilla-javascript-1f18408043f5). But this is not very practical as it requires the entire codebase to be written like this.

##### Background / Motivation

Using context like this is incredibly valuable because the context is available deep down the call-stack. This is especially useful if a library needs to call an external handler such that if the handler calls back to the library, the library will have the appropriate context. For example, I'd imagine React hooks and Solid.js extensively use context in this way under-the-hood. If not done this way, the programmer would have to pass a context object around everywhere and use it when calling back to the library, which is both messy and error-prone. Context is a way to neatly "curry" or abstract away a context object from function calls, based on where we are in the call stack. Whether it is good practice or not is debatable, but I think we can agree that it's something library authors have chosen to do. I would like to extend the use of context to asynchronous functions, which are supposed to conceptually behave like synchronous functions when it comes to the execution flow.

##### Bounty

I'm only realizing now that the previously-accepted answer does not work in browsers, as browsers do not implement async stack traces. I hope that an alternative hack is possible and so I am starting another bounty.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the advantages of this over using `.call()` or `.apply()` to provide a `this` binding for an invoked function?

Comment: Or `.bind()` to provide one or more already-bound versions of a function?

Comment: @Pointy The context is available deep down the call-stack. This is especially useful if a library needs to call an external handler such that if the handler calls back to the library, the library will have the appropriate context. For example, I'd imagine React hooks and Solid.js extensively use context in this way.

Comment: BTW as an alternative for creating a hack for contexts you might want want to use dependency injection instead.

Comment: @WolverinDEV Yeah absolutely. But if a single part of your codebase doesn't do DI (which is very common), then it messes everything up. And even with DI, you can't write code based on callstack context, which is arguably still important in some situations. With DI, you can use closures/similar to setup certain implementations within a kind of architectural scope, but not within the runtime function-call scope. These seem to be two distinct types of scopes where you would want to provide specific implementations, and this question covers the latter.

Comment: @WolverinDEV I believe in many cases developers care about the function-call scope when they should in fact be worrying about the architectural scope, but I still think there are rare situations where the function-call scope is what matters, which this question aims to address.

Comment: You mean: `const withContext = (ctx, func) => {` with a `=>`.  PS: A runnable snippet would be useful to experience the code on the spot.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks. The first snippet is now runnable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## 23.02.2023 Update

There is now a simple NPM module for providing sync and async function contexts:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/function-contexts

## Original Answer

As far as I know ECMA has no specification for "contexts" (regardless if it's a normal or async function).
Therefore the solution you posted for normal functions is already a hack.

As per ECMA standard, there is no JavaScript based API to hook await in order to do a generator like trick. So you have to rely on (environment based) hacks.
These hacks may highly depend on the environment you're using.

### JavaScript Only (requires async stack traces)

A solution which is purly based async stack traces is the following one.
Since nearly every JavaScript interpreter is based on V8 this works on nearly every use case.

```js
const kContextIdFunctionPrefix = "__context_id__";
const kContextIdRegex = new RegExp(`${kContextIdFunctionPrefix}([0-9]+)`);
let contextIdOffset = 0;

function runWithContextId(target, ...args) {
    const contextId = ++contextIdOffset;
    let proxy;
    eval(`proxy = async function ${kContextIdFunctionPrefix}${contextId}(target, ...args){ return await target.call(this, ...args); }`);
    return proxy.call(this, target, ...args);
}

function getContextId() {
    const stack = new Error().stack.split("\n");
    for(const frame of stack) {
        const match = frame.match(kContextIdRegex);
        if(!match) {
            continue;
        }

        const id = parseInt(match[1]);
        if(isNaN(id)) {
            console.warn(`Context id regex matched, but failed to parse context id from ${match[1]}`);
            continue;
        }

        return id;
    }

    console.log(new Error().stack)
    throw new Error("getContextId() called without providing a context (runWithContextId(...))");
}
```

A simple demo:

```js
async function main() {
    const target = async () => {
        const contextId = getContextId();
        console.log(`Context Id: ${contextId}`);
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        console.log(`Context Id (After await): ${getContextId()} (before: ${contextId})`);

        return contextId;
    };

    const contextIdA = runWithContextId(target);
    const contextIdB = runWithContextId(target);

    // Note: We're first awaiting the second call!
    console.log(`Invoke #2 context id: ${await contextIdB}`);
    console.log(`Invoke #1 context id: ${await contextIdA}`);
}
main();
```

This solution leverages stack traces in order to identify a context id. Traversing the (sync and async) stack trace and using dynamically generated functions with special names allows to pass a special value (a number in this instance).

### NodeJS (AsyncLocalStorage)

NodeJS offers a way for Asynchronous context tracking:
https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#class-asynclocalstorage
It should be possible to build an async context by using AsyncLocalStorage.

### Using a transpiler

You might want to use a transpiler (like babel or typescript) which convert async functions to generator functions on the fly.
Using a transpiler allows you to even write a plugin for implementing async contexts based on generator functions.

Comment: Haha that is a nice hack with the stack traces. Probably not too slow either.

Comment: Only realizing now that browsers don't implement async stack traces which is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

> Browsers do not implement async stack traces. An alternative answer is needed that works in both web and node.js environment

There is no good solution to this yet. However, the problem is recognised and being solved on the language level: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-context.

Until then, you can use [zone.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zone.js?activeTab=readme) which is developed for use in Angular but works independently as well. It solves this by monkey-patching `window.setTimeout` and `Promise.prototype.then` (and *every* single other asynchronous function) to capture the current `context` and wrap the callbacks in a `withContext` call to propagate the value.

Answer (score -1):

maybe bind? After bind you have new instance of function with captured "this" (in my case is null) or captured input params.

```
const timeout = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));


const foo = async function (context) {
  await timeout(1000);
  console.log(context);
};
const fooOuter = foo.bind(null, "calling from outer");

const bar = async () => {
  await fooOuter();
  await foo("calling from bar");
};
```

Comment: This does not meet my requirements for writing "context-specific code without having to pass around a context object everywhere and have every function we use depend on this context object" and having the context "available deep down the call-stack" in a way that is not "error-prone".